What is a "Chemikalie"
What is a Chemikalie?
Don't tell me it's a chemical if you don't tell me what a chemical is.
I see the word used in contexts suggesting it is the opposite of a natural substance, and sometimes it feels like it has a connotation of man made and evil.

What exactly is unclear after you consulted a dictionary?

In what manner is the German term different from the Englisch term? Why do you ask this question in German.stackexchange? Why is this article not helpful for you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_substance

The word die Chemikalie is only used for substances that are a product or intermediate product of technical processes. Everything that can be found in nature is die Substanz. The latter is an umbrella term.
So for example Harnstoff is a Substanz but it becomes a Chemikalie if it's produced in a technical process.
There's a grey area with technical processes that involve microorganisms, as well as with substances as e.g. Vanillin that are typically produced with technical processes but are available in food grades.

Sometimes things are so obvious that you can't see them. But as an afterthought, whisky is a "Chemikalie" (as produced by the technical process of distillation and not otherwise found in nature), but beer and wine are not?

I feel that the reasons are not language based, so I will not continue on this.

Whisky isn't a single Substanz but a mix, so you can't apply this terminology to it at all. That “technical process” is really something to discuss in corner cases. If it's a traditional method it's likely not a technical process but “cooking, and similar things”.

It is growing into a discussion, and outside of language. Just replace whiskey, beer and wine by "alcohol" provided by those.

There seems to a significant difference between "Chemikalie" and English "chemical". The English word applies to any relatively pure compound regardless of source, so water, sugar, diamond & table salt are all chemicals, at least in the technical sense. At least that's what Wikipedia says. Meanwhile a "Chemikalie" is produced by a technical process (lab or industrial) and can be a mixture. In common usage "chemical" is more like "Chemikalie" -- "I don't want chemicals in my food."

Regarding the last paragraph in the question, yes, that's true, "Chemikalien" is often used in that negative sense: "Iss doch mal was Ordentliches, Kind, deine Fertiggerichte sind doch alle voll von Chemikalien!" or even "Unser Orangensaft enhält keine Chemikalien!"

I think the term "Chemikalie" is also related to the intended use for a technical process. Alcohol can be a "Chemikalie" for a chemical experiment or a "Zutat" (=ingredient) for a Liqueur. The German Wikipedia page states in the first paragraph that the use of the term "Chemikalie" depends on the context.

I disagree with Janka.
We might argue what the definition of a technical process is. Of course, the substance doesn't change if it is used in a technical process, nor does it depend on being in such a process.
But the language between scientists, reasoning about it and engineers of such processes differs from the usage of ordinary people. In both cases, a tomato contains H2O; salt, eaten by people, is a Chemikalie, whether or not it was taken from the ocean or from below the ground and how far it was processed later.
A Chemikalie will mostly be considered as something pure or nearly pure, depending on context, again.
And of course, a cake is the result of a technical process, but in nearly no situation, somebody would call the cake a Chemikalie.

Your question is not about the meaning, but about the connotations of the word. It looks like you stumbled across a cultural concept which you have not encountered outside of German language. I was not aware that this is something special about German, but it might be.
Amongst speakers of German, there is a widespread scepticism towards chemistry and chemical products. This prejudice does not exist among the whole population, but it is a mainstream idea / ideology. You will find it regularly in advertisements, stressing that a produce has only natural ingredients, with the idea being implied that it has no chemicals. Also, the word Chemie can be used in a similar negative way as you noticed it about Chemikalie. A common phrase is ohne Chemie ("without chemistry"), which only makes sense in the context of the aforementioned idea of chemistry, but cannot be taken literally.
The idea comes in different flavors and is taken to different grades, but you are right that in its extreme formulation the underlying concept is that Chemie was evil.
